# Binding to a WPF hosted control's DependencyProperty in WinForms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, data-binding, elementhost

I have a WinForms app with some elements that are hosted WPF user controls (using ElementHost).

I want to be able to bind my WinForm's control property (`Button.Enabled`) to a custom DependencyProperty of the hosted WPF user control (`SearchResults.IsAccountSelected`).

Is it possible to bind a System.Windows.Forms.Binding to a property managed by a DependencyProperty?

Also, since I know the System.Windows.Forms.Binding watches for `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` events - will a property backed by a DependencyProperty automatically fire these events or will I have to implement and manage the sending of PropertyChanged events manually?

Comment: Seems like if you could, would be a severe hack. Might not be the best route to take.

Comment: @jsmith - Using a binding might not be the best route to take? What other problems do you perceive? Is UI cross-threading a consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DependencyObject` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so if you take this route you will have to implement the sending of PropertyChanged events manually.

Fortunately `DependencyObject` does have the `OnPropertyChanged` method, so implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `DependencyObject`-derived class is trivial, for example:

```
public class MyClass : HeaderedContentControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if(handler!=null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(e.Property.Name));
    base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
  }
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

I'd like to echo jsmith's thought that binding directly to a UserControl property may not be the best route to take.  In most cases MVVM is a better way to go.  There are exceptions, of course.

Comment: Can someone elaborate on the MVVM suggestion? Specifically how this would somehow help the outer (winforms) app know that something just happened in the inner (wpf) control.

Comment: If you have a view model that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, both the WinForms and WPF can bind to the same model.  So in the example above, you would bind  the WinForms Button.Enabled and the WPF SearchResults.IsAccountSelected to the same model property.  In other words, instead of storing the actual search results in a WPF SearchResults control, you would have a SearchResults object in your model or view model, and the WPF control would be SearchResultsView and bind to it.