# Binding a WPF element host to a WinForm property

Tags: wpf, winforms, binding, elementhost

I have a `WPF element host` sitting in a `WinForm`.

I would like to **bind a property of the element to a property of the WinForm.**

In my searches I found the opposite solution, binding between WinForms to WPF properties (when the WinForm is sitting on a WPF host).

Here is an example:
**[How to bind a windows control in WPF????](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/bind-windows-control-wpf-31666.aspx)**

I also saw this answer (not exactly an answer, I'd say a conclusion): **[Binding to a WPF hosted control's DependencyProperty in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041027/binding-to-a-wpf-hosted-controls-dependencyproperty-in-winforms)**

It did not help me. I also want to keep the the principle of MVVM in the WPF element host.

|It there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it this way:

I created a property in `ViewModel` and **init him through the `WinForm`** when I use the wpf host control in the first time.

I binding the property to element in `xaml`

and that's all.

Comment: I have the same problem at the moment. Can you please more collaborate, share some codes? Thanks